# R: No applicable method for 'tbl' error when making a SQL Server query using dplyr and pool

Tags: sql-server, r, dplyr, pool

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere, but I could not find it. With the following code I am connecting to an MS SQL database using the RJDBC mechanism using pooling from the pool package:

```
library(RJDBC)
library(DBI)
library(pool)
library(dplyr)

drv <-
  JDBC(
    "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
    "C:/R/RJDBC/Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server/sqljdbc_6.0/enu/jre8/sqljdbc42.jar"
  )

pool_instance <- dbPool(
  drv = drv,
  dbname = "dbasename",
  url = "jdbc:sqlserver://sql01",
  user = "user",
  password = "password"
)

mydata <- dbGetQuery(pool_instance, "select * from my.Table")
src_pool(pool_instance) %>% tbl("my.Table") %>% head(5)
```

When I run this code, I make a successful connection to my SQL Server database and the `dbGetQuery` function call retrieves the data as expected.

However, when I call the `src_pool` function I get the following error message:

> Error in UseMethod("tbl") :    no applicable method for 'tbl' applied
>   to an object of class "c('src_', 'src_sql', 'src')"

If I call the function `src_pool(pool_instance)` separately, without piping to the tbl function, the error message is similar:

> Error in UseMethod("src_desc") :    no applicable method for
>   'src_desc' applied to an object of class "c('src_', 'src_sql', 'src')"

I expected that either dplyr or pool would provide for these methods? Do I need to write code for these methods? What am I missing?

Note that I am a newby to SQL Server database connectivity.

Comment: I just read an [R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/accessing-mssql-server-with-r-rsqlserver-with-dplyr/) post that suggest that the schema table cannot have a dot (.). The real name of the table in the dbase schema contains a dot, just as my.Table does.

Comment: Try something like this: `pool_instance %>% tbl(in_schema("my", "Table"))`.  You might need to install and load the `tidyverse` and `dbplyr` packages as well.

Comment: Update from 2022, the issue is yet happening as commented by @Paul van Oppen, so when calling with pool and tbl, you have to use something liek this: `conn %>% tbl(sql("SELECT * FROM schema.table"))`